# The React Typescript Form submit button is not working

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-typescript

I have the below Form component that I'd like to use to pass user input from one component to another.

Below is the code for the Form:

```
<Modal
                isOpen={filterModal}
                toggle={collectionsCustomersFilterToggle}
                centered={true}>
                <ModalHeader>Filter Customers by</ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(set_filter)}>
                        <FormGroup row className="pb-2">
                            <Label for="customerNameFilterText" sm={4}>
                                Customer Name
                            </Label>
                            <Col sm={8}>
                                <Input 
                                    {...register('customerNameFilterText')}
                                    className="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Search by Customer Name"
                                    type="text"/>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>

                        -------------

                        <FormGroup check row>
                            <Row>
                                <Col sm={4}>
                                    <Button
                                        className="view btn-secondary"
                                        type="button">
                                            Clear Filters
                                    </Button>
                                </Col>
                                <Col sm={4}></Col>
                                <Col sm={4}>
                                    <Button
                                        className="btn-primary"
                                        type="submit">
                                            Apply Filters
                                    </Button>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </form>
                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
```

Below is it implementation to handle submitted data as I am using the React useForm hook:

```
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors }
    } = useForm();

    const set_filter = (data: FiltersProps) => {
        collectionsCustomersFilterToggle();
        applyFilter(data);
        console.log("data",data);   
    };
```

The problem is that on submitting and I log the data, all the object properties are undefined even after user input.

Assistance would be greatly appreciated if there is somewhere that I may have overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you provided, it looks like you are using the react-hook-form library to handle form submission. However, it seems that you are not properly binding the form inputs to the useForm hook.

To fix this problem, you need to use the "name" attribute on the input element and pass it to the registration function. This will allow react-hook-form to bind the input value to the form data object correctly.

Here is an updated version of your code with the necessary changes:

```
    <Modal isOpen={filterModal} toggle={collectionsCustomersFilterToggle} centered={true}>
  <ModalHeader>Filter Customers by</ModalHeader>
  <ModalBody>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(set_filter)}>
      <FormGroup row className="pb-2">
        <Label for="customerNameFilterText" sm={4}>
          Customer Name
        </Label>
        <Col sm={8}>
          <Input
            {...register('customerNameFilterText')}
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Search by Customer Name"
            type="text"
            name="customerNameFilterText" // Add the name attribute
          />
        </Col>
      </FormGroup>

      {/* Rest of the form */}

      <FormGroup check row>
        <Row>
          <Col sm={4}>
            <Button className="view btn-secondary" type="button">
              Clear Filters
            </Button>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={4}></Col>
          <Col sm={4}>
            <Button className="btn-primary" type="submit">
              Apply Filters
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </FormGroup>
    </form>
  </ModalBody>
</Modal>
```

By adding the `name` attribute to the `Input` element and passing it to the `register` function, react-hook-form will correctly bind the input value to the `data` object in the `set_filter` function.